# How would you fix this segmentation fault when referencing a 2d array?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is a recursive function in c that references a 2d array while returning values for every `int` surrounding the reference point, yet whenever I run the function I get a segmentation fault. Here's the code:

```c
int blobDetect(int** picture, int x, int y, int limit)
{  
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= limit || y >= limit || picture[x][y] != 1)
        return 0;
    else if (picture[x][y] == 1)
    {
        return 1 +
            blobDetect(picture, x + 1, y,     limit) +
            blobDetect(picture, x - 1, y,     limit) +
            blobDetect(picture, x,     y - 1, limit) +
            blobDetect(picture, x,     y + 1, limit) +
            blobDetect(picture, x - 1, y - 1, limit) +
            blobDetect(picture, x + 1, y - 1, limit) +
            blobDetect(picture, x - 1, y + 1, limit) +
            blobDetect(picture, x + 1, y + 1, limit);
    }
}
```

Comment: There does not appear to be an end condition. It will call recursively +1, -1, +1, -1 until stack overflow. (Guess you came to the right place)

Comment: @stark I thought that the if(x<0 || y<0 || x>=limit || y>=limit || picture[x][y] != 1 ) return 0; statement would be the end condition

Comment: *This is a recursive function in c that references a 2d array...*  No, it references a one-dimensional array of pointers to separate, individual one-dimensional arrays of `int` values.  If you're passing in a true two-dimensional array, such as `int array[x][y]`, your code will fail because of that.

Comment: @Andrew Henle I am passing an array later in the code, picture[x][y], what part of my code is incorrect in passing the recursive function? I'm new to recursion

Comment: "*I thought that..would be the end condition*. It's an end condition but the recursive calls mean that some branches of the recursion will never end. Think of it this sequence. You have a `blobDetect(x+1)` which then calls `blobDetect(x-1)` which then calls `blobDetect(x+1)` and so on. See how that sequence never ends?

Comment: problem almost certainly lies in the called code, please add that to the question

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question has multiple errors. Firstly, although `int*` may seem equivalent to a 1D array of `int`, `int**` is not at all equivalent to 2D array of `int`. Instead `int**` is equivalent to 1D array of `int*`, which I guess is not what you wanted.

To accept a 2D array as argument, without knowing their dimensions at compile time, you should declare function as one of the below.

Using VLAs in C99:

```
int blobDetect(int limit, int picture[limit][limit], int x, int y);
```

Using a single pointer:

```
int blobDetect(int* picture, int x, int y, int limit);
// in this case, you may need to explicitely cast 2D array to `int*` when calling the function to suppress warnings
// blobDetect((int*)pic, x, y, lim);
```

Secondly, there is problem of infinite recursion. You may need to change the logic of the program. I am not sure what you are trying to calculate exactly, so I can't help.

Thirdly, you are not returning anything if both if conditions fail in your code. Based on your convenience, you may need to return something like `-1` to indicate failure. If you are absolutely sure that, control never reaches there, document it properly using comments.